# Traffic flow data XML tags meaning

Tags: traffic, here-api

I am looking for real-time traffic flow data. I found the traffic API is what I need:
Click [here](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/traffic/topics_v6.1/example-flow-bounding-box.html)
but I really don't know what the meanings are for those XML tags, such as 
`<FI>`
`<TMC PC="11531" DE="Linden" QD="-" LE="0.8535"/>`
`<CF CN="0.86" FF="69.59" JF="0.17" SP="70.13" TY="TR"/>`
`</FI>`
I found the meaning of TMC DE PC
But I cannot find CF CN FF JF SP TY.

Anyone know these abbreviations ?

Many thanks,

Chuansheng

Comment: The link requires signing in, which not many people will want to do, so you may be out of luck. Meanwhile I'm deleting the XML tag, since this is not a question about generic XML technology.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that it's quite hidden, but you can find the explanation for xsd schemas under the [meta resources](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/traffic/topics/additional-parameters.html).
You are most likely interested in the following REST call:

http://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.0/xsd/flow.xsd?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&app_code=YOUR_APP_CODE

Here is part of the output explaining what **FF** attribute stands for:

```
...
<xs:attribute name="FF" type="speed" use="required">
   <xs:annotation>
     <xs:documentation>The free flow speed on this stretch of road.</xs:documentation>
   </xs:annotation>
</xs:attribute>
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Those are related to the Traffic Message Channel information where the included information are the event id, the location code, expected incident duration, affected extent and other details.

Those TMC are managed in different ways depending on the country you are interested in and specialised mapping data provider can give you access to those kind of information and that's what the subscription is about. It is also related to the way you can use the TMC depending on the concerned area to get or give information from there.

For more information about TMC: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_message_channel

The complete information about it is retrieved from Here Platform could be find in the documentation:

[https://developer.here.com/documentation/download/traffic_nlp/6.0.28.1/Traffic%20API%20v6.0.28.1%20Developer's%20Guide.pdf](https://developer.here.com/documentation/download/traffic_nlp/6.0.28.1/Traffic%20API%20v6.0.28.1%20Developer%27s%20Guide.pdf)

Answer (score -2):

In general I would think that the [developer docs](https://developer.here.com/documentation/versions) should have all information needed to use the API, did not check them, but as the pages are not having any other place, I would suggest checking those.

Then if they fail to provide the information, then would suggest contacting the here support directly.