# Reading traffic flow data from HERE maps rest API

Tags: here-api

I am trying to use HERE maps REST API to get information about real-time traffic flow. The sample requests in HERE documentation work fine, however, I cannot find anywhere any documentation of the response (meaning of particular tags, such as `<TRAFFICML_REALTIME>`, `<FIS>` or `<RW>`).

Does anyone know how to obtain such a documentation?

Note: On HERE website I have found that all technical questions should be posted here and that their development support team is actively monitoring StackOverflow. There is no direct option to contact them.

Comment: It looks like this question has been [answered previously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394499/traffic-flow-data-xml-tags-meaning)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should find it under "Meta Resources" in the documentation, following should provide the required info

http://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.0/xsd/flow.xsd?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL%20&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

Answer (score 9):

Some of the tag meanings

- "**RWS**" - A list of Roadway (RW) items
- "**RW**" = This is the composite item for flow across an entire roadway. A roadway item will be present for each roadway with traffic flow information available
- "**FIS**" = A list of Flow Item (FI) elements
- "**FI**" = A single flow item
- "**TMC**" = An ordered collection of TMC locations
- "**PC**" = Point TMC Location Code
- "**DE**" = Text description of the road
- "**QD**" = Queuing direction. '+' or '-'. Note this is the opposite of the travel direction in the fully qualified ID, For example for location 107+03021 the QD would be '-'
- "**LE**" = Length of the stretch of road. The units are defined in the file header
- "**CF**" = Current Flow. This element contains details about speed and Jam Factor information for the given flow item.
- "**CN**" = Confidence, an indication of how the speed was determined. -1.0 road closed. 1.0=100% 0.7-100% Historical Usually a value between .7 and 1.0
- "**FF**" = The free flow speed on this stretch of road.
- "**JF**" = The number between 0.0 and 10.0 indicating the expected quality of travel. When there is a road closure, the Jam Factor will be 10. As the number approaches 10.0 the quality of travel is getting worse. -1.0 indicates that a Jam Factor could not be calculated
- "**SP**" = Speed (based on UNITS) capped by speed limit
- "**SU**" = Speed (based on UNITS) not capped by speed limit
- "**TY**" = Type information for the given Location Referencing container. This may be freely defined string