# Understanding the Data given by HERE Flow API

Tags: here-api

so i was wondering if someone can explain the formatting of the flow api JSON output. When I get it I get one road per FI but then I get another road name printed out for the FIS. I dont understand where this road name is coming from and what it has to do with the other roads.

```
''''{'RWS': [{'RW': [{'FIS': [{'FI': [{'TMC': {'PC': 5243, 'DE': 'New Hwy/Exit 34', 'QD': '+', 'LE': 0.55152}, 'SHP': [], 'CF': [{'TY': 'TR', 'SP': 55.3, 'SU': 57.85, 'FF': 55.3, 'JF': 0.0, 'CN': 0.99}]}, {'TMC': {'PC': 5242, 'DE': 'RT-109/Exit 33', 'QD': '+', 'LE': 0.18784}, 'SHP': [], 'CF': [{'TY': 'TR', 'SP': 55.3, 'SU': 55.77, 'FF': 55.24, 'JF': 0.0, 'CN': 0.99}]}, {'TMC': {'PC': 5241, 'DE': 'RT-110/Southern St Pky/Exit 32', 'QD': '+', 'LE': 1.47864}, 'SHP': [], 'CF': [{'TY': 'TR', 'SP': 55.3, 'SU': 58.54, 'FF': 55.18, 'JF': 0.0, 'CN': 0.99}]}, {'TMC': {'PC': 5240, 'DE': 'Bethpage Pky/Linden St/Exit 31', 'QD': '+', 'LE': 1.26445}, 'SHP': [], 'CF': [{'TY': 'TR', 'SP': 55.3, 'SU': 56.6, 'FF': 55.24, 'JF': 0.0, 'CN': 0.99}]}]}], 'mid': 'a50f8d5f-dfdc-48e3-aa87-1bfe32700420', 'LI': '120-00149', 'DE': 'Southern Pky', 'PBT': '2019-12-20T13:45:26Z'}, {'FIS': [{'FI': [{'TMC': {'PC': 5241, 'DE': 'RT-110/Southern St Pky/Exit 32', 'QD': '-', 'LE': 1.53152}, 'SHP': [], 'CF': [{'TY': 'TR', 'SP': 55.3, 'SU': 57.24, 'FF': 55.3, 'JF': 0.0, 'CN': 0.99}]}, {'TMC': {'PC': 5242, 'DE': 'RT-109/Exit 33', 'QD': '-', 'LE': 1.2702}, 'SHP': [], 'CF': [{'TY': 'TR', 'SP': 55.3, 'SU': 62.27, 'FF': 55.3, 'JF': 0.0, 'CN': 0.99}]}, {'TMC': {'PC': 5243, 'DE': 'New Hwy/Exit 34', 'QD': '-', 'LE': 0.2446}, 'SHP': [], 'CF': [{'TY': 'TR', 'SP': 55.3, 'SU': 55.76, 'FF': 55.3, 'JF': 0.0, 'CN': 0.99}]}, {'TMC': {'PC': 5244, 'DE': 'CR-3/Wellwood Ave/Exit 35', 'QD': '-', 'LE': 0.6373}, 'SHP': [], 'CF': [{'TY': 'TR', 'SP': 55.3, 'SU': 64.07, 'FF': 55.3, 'JF': 0.0, 'CN': 0.99}]}]}], 'mid': '92d68ef7-1db2-4089-8560-e64fe2cb98d0', 'LI': '120+00149', 'DE': 'Southern Pky', 'PBT': '2019-12-20T13:46:23Z'}''''
```

I am talking about this part here

```
'mid': '92d68ef7-1db2-4089-8560-e64fe2cb98d0', 'LI': '120+00149', 'DE': 'Southern Pky', 'PBT': '2019-12-20T13:46:23Z'}
```

where is this road name coming from

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28476762/11301900

Answer (score 0):

You should find it under "Meta Resources" in the documentation, following should provide the required info

http://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.0/xsd/flow.xsd?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL%20&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg