# Interpreting HERE Maps real-time traffic tags

Tags: here-api

I've read all the HERE Maps API documentation but couldn't find the answer. What is the meaning of the XML tags in the HERE real-time traffic REST API output?

```
<FI><TMC PC="4375" DE="Rivonia Road" QD="-" LE="0.55047"/><CF CN="0.83" FF="24.0" JF="6.8228" SP="10.78" SU="10.78" TY="TR"/></FI>
```

Does anyone know how to interpret this output (I used proximity parameter in my request)?

Comment: Please see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394499/traffic-flow-data-xml-tags-meaning/34103133#34103133).

Comment: OK - thank you for the hint

Answer (score 20):

I noticed that a lot of people have this question and the answer is somewhat difficult to find. I've posted a list of the tag meanings I could find below.

- "RWS" - A list of Roadway (RW) items
- "RW" = This is the composite item for flow across an entire roadway.
  A roadway item will be present for each roadway with traffic flow
  information available
- "FIS" = A list of Flow Item (FI) elements
- "FI" = A single flow item
- "TMC" = An ordered collection of TMC locations
- "PC" = Point TMC Location Code
- "DE" = Text description of the road
- "QD" = Queuing direction. '+' or '-'. Note this is the opposite of
  the travel direction in the fully qualified ID, For example for
  location 107+03021 the QD would be '-'
- "LE" = Length of the stretch of road.  The units are defined in the
  file header
- "CF" = Current Flow. This element contains details about speed and
   Jam Factor information for the given flow item.
- "CN" = Confidence, an indication of how the speed was determined.
   -1.0 road closed. 1.0=100%  0.7-100% Historical Usually a value between .7 and 1.0
- "FF" = The free flow speed on this stretch of road.
- "JF" = The number between 0.0 and 10.0 indicating the expected
  quality of travel. When there is a road closure, the Jam Factor will
  be 10. As the number approaches 10.0 the quality of travel is getting
  worse. -1.0 indicates that a Jam Factor could not be calculated
- "SP" = Speed (based on UNITS) capped by speed limit
- "SU" = Speed (based on UNITS) not capped by speed limit
- "TY" = Type information for the given Location Referencing container.
  This may be freely defined string

Source: http://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.0/xsd/flow.xsd?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&app_code=YOUR_APP_CODE

Comment: There is a more complete description in a PDF document provided by them: http://documentation.developer.here.com/pdf/traffic_hlp/6.0.68.0/Traffic%20API%20v6.0.68.0%20Developer's%20Guide.pdf

Comment: BTW, how do I determine the Fully Qualified ID descripted in the QD field?