# (Why) 'dont my credentials authorize access' to any descriptive meta resources from the HERE-api?

Tags: here-api

Yesterday I registered with HERE to experiment on Traffic/Flow data.
I registered with both the 'Public Basic plan' as well as the '90-day evaluation'. I managed to perform some basic query's and also got results but the next step was to understand the output.

The official way to get descriptions on the output data is described here:
https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/traffic/topics/additional-parameters.html.

I simply substituted my credentials in the the https://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.0/xsd/flow.xsd?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE} URL and pasted in my browser. But the only result I get for every xsd is:
*"error:These credentials do not authorize access. Please contact your customer representative or submit a request here developer.here.com/contact-us to upgrade your account. You can also get valid credentials by registering for a free trial license on developer.here.com.,error_description:NA"* . So apparently I am authorized to use the api but not authorized to get information on how to interpret the results...?

I already found out the many abbreviation are explained on [Interpreting HERE Maps real-time traffic tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066427/interpreting-here-maps-real-time-traffic-tags/34150385#34150385) but I found a few that weren't described, like <**SSS**> and <**SS**>.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** Apparently I was already voted down on the question. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not the voter, so this is just a guess, but it could be because the question title makes it like your problem is a customer service issue, not a programming problem. You might have better luck if you re-word this so you're asking how to provide your authorization correctly so you stop getting the unauthorized message. You'll also need to provide the existing code you're attempting to run so someone can see what the problem is. (Also, don't use the question space to talk about voting on the question.)

Comment: Thanks @BSMP for your comment. You're actualy right, because the guys at here.com instruct us to post questions on the api on SO (https://developer.here.com/faqs#developer-support). But I'll rephrase my question again and extend my details. 

Regarding my 'update' I was hoping people would tell me what I was doing wrong, instead of only down voting my question. This way newbees never learn.

Comment: I am running into the same issue. https://cit.transit.api.here.com/v3/lines/by_stn_id.json is the end point I am trying to access. Tried with credentials from both basic & evaluation licenses. @RezDev, did you get any response from the HERE support team?

Comment: @praneel, nope. Also not working on the project anymore.

Comment: @praneel are you still facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The Description of **SS/SSS** tag is here:

> The **SS (SUB_SEGMENT)** will be provided if the current traffic data is
>   more precise than the road defined. When there are SS elements, the
>   elements will be ordered by driving direction. If there are SS
>   elements, the lengths (LE) of all SS elements will add up to the
>   length of the roadway represented from the corresponding CF section.