# Understand realtime traffic with HERE developer

Tags: traffic, opendata

I try to use the service HERE developer to get in realtime datas about trafic anywhere in the world.

The API returns me lot of datas, but I really don't know how to use them to understand if in a specific area / road there are lot of traffic or not.

If someone know how to use it and have an idea about my question, thank you !

For example, If I have that :

```
                        "TMC":{  
                           "PC":53877,
                           "DE":"Rue Beurbroucq",
                           "QD":"+",
                           "LE":0.34268
                        },
                        "SHP":[  

                        ],
                        "CF":[  
                           {  
                              "TY":"TR",
                              "SP":15.22,
                              "SU":15.22,
                              "FF":26.1,
                              "JF":4.42643,
                              "CN":0.91
                           }
```

I want to know if there are lot of traffic or not in the street.
Is it possible with theses datas? 
I understand the differents datas provided, but I don't understand how to link them.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried and where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: I edit my post, thx !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interpreting HERE Maps real-time traffic tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066427/interpreting-here-maps-real-time-traffic-tags)