# Traffic API - Flow within Bounding Box Tag Meaning?

Tags: here-api

I would like to use the Traffic Flow API - "Flow within Bounding Box" to get data on the average speed of vehicles.

An example seen here (https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/traffic/traffic-flow-bounding-box) is

```
                "TMC": {
                "PC": 32483,
                "DE": "SOHO",
                "QD": "+",
                "LE": 0.71306
              },
              "SHP": [],
              "CF": [
                {
                  "TY": "TR",
                  "SP": 8.44,
                  "SU": 8.44,
                  "FF": 15.8,
                  "JF": 3.15577,
                  "CN": 0.98
```

I'm confused about 3 of the tags. In an earlier post, someone posted the meanings of the tags here
[Interpreting HERE Maps real-time traffic tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066427/interpreting-here-maps-real-time-traffic-tags/34150385#34150385)

I'm looking specifically at the speed tags, i.e.

```
 "FF" = The free flow speed on this stretch of road. 
 "SP" = Speed (based on UNITS) capped by speed limit 
 "SU" = Speed (based on UNITS) not capped by speed limit
```

Could someone explain the difference between these 3?

In some examples, "SP"/"SU" is larger than "FF"?

For example (entering coordinates 45.0395,7.6116;45.0224,7.6611 into bbox)

```
                "TMC": {
                "PC": 14176,
                "DE": "Mirafiori",
                "QD": "+",
                "LE": 0.60245
              },
              "SHP": [],
              "CF": [
                {
                  "TY": "TR",
                  "SP": 41.4,
                  "SU": 56.3,
                  "FF": 40.4,
                  "JF": 0,
                  "CN": 0.94
```

Answer (score 0):

"FF" = This indicates the speed on the segment at which vehicles should be considered to be able to travel without impediment. This speed is calculated as a percentile of observed speeds during non-rush hour.

"SP" = The average speed, capped by the speed limit, that current traffic is travelling.

"SU" = The average speed, uncapped by the speed limit, that current traffic is travelling

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

So in the 2nd example in my original post, the speed limit is 41.4km/h (units is metric), while the actual traffic is doing 56.3km/h. But the free flow speed of 40.4km/h is less than actual traffic speed?