# What are LID, LE and FW in responses of here traffic API?

Tags: metadata, here-api

I am struggling to understand the response of here API traffic flow data. I went through the documentation but it seems that there are some important missing parts there.

For instance, details on returned parameters such as "LID", "LE", "FW" and "Criticality" are missing in the documentation. Also, the difference between "Original_traffic_item_id" and "traffic_item_id" in the response from incident API is completely missing. Or what is "TPEGOpenLRBase64"?

Here are links to pages which contain an example of such responses:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics_v6.1/example-flow-location-references.html

https://www.developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics/example-incidents-tmc-restrictions.html

https://www.developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics/incident-data.html

Am I missing something? Is there any other specific documentation somewhere that I have been unable to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the description of the element name for traffic API-

**TPEGOpenLRBase64** -[Binary data]Provided if TPEGOpenLRBase64 is the location referencing type for the containing RWS.

**SHP/LID** - [LinkID] The linkID will be in driving direction order; “F” represents travel direction FROM reference node, “T” represents travel direction TO reference node (For example 123456789T or 987654321F).

**SHP/LE** -Length of stretch of road defined by SHP element. The units are defined in the file header.

**SHP/FW**- Form of way. Possible values are Motorway (MW), Multi-digitized road which is not a motorway(MD), single digitized road (SD), Ramp/Slip (RA), Roundabout (RO), Undefined (UN).

For more acronym check this-
https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics/common-acronyms.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Is there a comprehensive document/link which contains such details for the aforementioned elements? I am still confused about some other elements such as "Original_traffic_item_id", etc.

Comment: Check this answer with a list of acronyms, and the link to get the actual documentation (with your credentials): https://stackoverflow.com/a/34150385/2437664