# Meaning of the response variables in Traffic Flow

Tags: here-api

so i am using the here.developer api in order to get data on traffic for a given area. I am using proximity to get the radius. I have the api working with python using requests and i have it printing out the data. I am confused though on what the data means. For example, i get this

```
{
  "RWS": [
    {
      "RW": [
        {
          "FIS": [
            {
              "FI": [
                {
                  "TMC": {
                    "PC": 6084,
                    "DE": "Johnson Ave/Kinderkamack Rd",
                    "QD": "+",
                    "LE": 0.94082
                  },
                  "SHP": [],
                  "CF": [
                    {
                      "TY": "TR",
                      "SP": 46.38,
                      "SU": 46.38,
                      "FF": 49.21,
                      "JF": 0.47912,
                      "CN": 0.99
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "TMC": {
                    "PC": 6083,
                    "DE": "CR-503/Hackensack Ave",
                    "QD": "+",
                    "LE": 0.43574
                  },
                  "SHP": [],
                  "CF": [
                    {
                      "TY": "TR",
                      "SP": 39.15,
                      "SU": 39.15,
                      "FF": 49.15,
                      "JF": 1.69619,
                      "CN": 0.99
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "TMC": {
                    "PC": 6082,
                    "DE": "River Rd",
                    "QD": "+",
                    "LE": 0.3682
                  },
                  "SHP": [],
                  "CF": [
                    {
                      "SSS": {
                        "SS": [
                          {
                            "LE": 0.13436,
                            "SP": 35.11,
                            "SU": 35.11,
                            "FF": 49.4,
                            "JF": 2.41044
                          },
                          {
                            "LE": 0.23383,
                            "SP": 23.14,
                            "SU": 23.14,
                            "FF": 49.09,
                            "JF": 5.21289
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      "TY": "TR",
                      "SP": 24.57,
                      "SU": 24.57,
                      "FF": 49.21,
                      "JF": 3.85751,
                      "CN": 0.99
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "TMC": {
                    "PC": 6081,
                    "DE": "Teaneck Rd",
                    "QD": "+",
                    "LE": 1.47647
                  },
                  "SHP": [],
                  "CF": [
                    {
                      "SSS": {
                        "SS": [
                          {
                            "LE": 0.54181,
                            "SP": 13.99,
                            "SU": 13.99,
                            "FF": 49.09,
                            "JF": 8.45597
                          },
                          {
                            "LE": 0.12603,
                            "SP": 22,
                            "SU": 22,
                            "FF": 49.09,
                            "JF": 5.79388
                          },
                          {
                            "LE": 0.80862,
                            "SP": 32.08,
                            "SU": 32.08,
                            "FF": 49.28,
                            "JF": 2.90814
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      "TY": "TR",
                      "SP": 19.33,
                      "SU": 19.33,
                      "FF": 49.21,
                      "JF": 6.23169,
                      "CN": 0.99
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "mid": "0a507b9f-0c71-425a-93ba-9cb2d1e91c48",
          "LI": "120-00219",
          "DE": "RT-4",
          "PBT": "2019-12-18T15:57:25Z"
        },
        {
          "FIS": [
            {
              "FI": [
                {
                  "TMC": {
                    "PC": 6082,
                    "DE": "River Rd",
                    "QD": "-",
                    "LE": 1.43747
                  },
                  "SHP": [],
                  "CF": [
                    {
                      "TY": "TR",
                      "SP": 49.71,
                      "SU": 49.84,
                      "FF": 49.71,
                      "JF": 0,
                      "CN": 0.99
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "TMC": {
                    "PC": 6083,
                    "DE": "CR-503/Hackensack Ave",
                    "QD": "-",
                    "LE": 0.61971
                  },
                  "SHP": [],
                  "CF": [
                    {
                      "TY": "TR",
                      "SP": 49.71,
                      "SU": 51.04,
                      "FF": 49.21,
                      "JF": 0,
                      "CN": 0.99
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "TMC": {
                    "PC": 6084,
                    "DE": "Johnson Ave/Kinderkamack Rd",
                    "QD": "-",
                    "LE": 0.42619
                  },
                  "SHP": [],
                  "CF": [
                    {
                      "TY": "TR",
                      "SP": 49.71,
                      "SU": 51.02,
                      "FF": 49.09,
                      "JF": 0,
                      "CN": 0.99
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "mid": "70f7c3fd-51b0-43ed-916c-65b510791154",
          "LI": "120+00219",
          "DE": "RT-4",
          "PBT": "2019-12-18T15:56:39Z"
        }
```

I dont understand what most of there mean like "RWS", "FIS", "DE", "PC" "LE", "CF" "TY", "TR", and a bunch bunch more. Where can i find documentation on all this because i have searched and found nothing

Comment: This is off-topic IMO.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile why would you say that? for python? sorry yeah youre prob right i just included it because im using python to get it my bad.

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant for specific technical problems, this is a question about documentation for some random company's API. It's explained much better here: [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AlexanderCécile yeah but they had a tag and linked it on their help so i figured it would be a good place to ask

Comment: https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics/common-acronyms.html

Comment: @AlexanderCécile thank you appropriate your help. i actually found that before but it doesn't give the definition for all the acronyms that are in the response

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28476762/11301900, https://stackoverflow.com/q/22394499/11301900

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Thank you so much that is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

TMCCodeType holds a value of the typexs:string with the following restrictions:

```
Fixed length: 5 characters
Format: ECC+CCD+Table, where the following rules apply:

ECC is the Extended Country Code.
CCD is the TMC country code.
Table   is the defined TMC Table
```

You should find it under "Meta Resources" in the documentation, following should provide the required info

> traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.0/xsd/flow.xsd?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL%20&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg
>
> developer.here.com/documentation/download/traffic_nlp/6.0.28.1/Traffic%20API%20v6.0.28.1%20Developer's%20Guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I've found in the [hereR API](https://rdrr.io/) some definitions that may help:
"""
The maximum width and height of the bounding box of the input AOIs is 10 degrees. This means that each polygon (= one row) in the AOI sf object should fit in a 10 x 10 degree bbox.

Explanation of the traffic flow variables:

"PC": Point TMC location code.

"DE": Text description of the road.

"QD": Queuing direction. '+' or '-'. Note this is the opposite of the travel direction in the fully qualified ID, For example for location 107+03021 the QD would be '-'.

"LE": Length of the stretch of road.

"TY": Type information for the given Location Referencing container. This may be a freely defined string.

"SP": Speed (based on UNITS) capped by speed limit.

"FF": The free flow speed on this stretch of the road.

"JF": The number between 0.0 and 10.0 indicating the expected quality of travel. When there is a road closure, the Jam Factor will be 10. As the number approaches 10.0 the quality of travel is getting worse. -1.0 indicates that a Jam Factor could not be calculated.

"CN": Confidence, an indication of how the speed was determined. -1.0 road closed. 1.0=100%.
"""